# Excel 2010 VBA: Save file using value from cell to determine path and filename

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to write some code that will save several tabs as a pdf document in folder specified by files within excell. I would like for cells within the document to dictate where this file is saved. I am not sure if this is possibly, but if it is any help would be good! I am currently getting a Run-time error '1004' during the save process of my code.

And yes, I do have the folders created that are being referenced.

```
Sub asdf()

Dim Fname As String
Dim Fpath As String
Dim YrMth As String

Fname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text

YrMth = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Text & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Text

Fpath = "C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\" & YrMth & "\Group\" & Fname & ".pdf"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")).Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Fpath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, but not with the path you've specified.

Declare a new string variable:

```
dim myDocsPath as String
```

Get the path using:

```
myDocsPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\"
```

and then change your definition for Fpath to:

```
Fpath = myDocsPath & YrMth & "\Group\" & Fname & ".pdf"
```

If I change the end of `myDocsPath` to `& "\My foo Documents\"` I get the same 1004 error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your insights Head of Catering!

Answer (score 1):

Try replace line in your code

```
Fpath = "C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\" & YrMth & "\Group\" & Fname & ".pdf"
```

with

```
Dim WshShell As Object
Dim MyDocsFolder As String
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyDocsFolder = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\"

Fpath = MyDocsFolder & YrMth & "\Group\" & Fname & ".pdf"
```

Edit:
The core of this solution is in line:

```
MyDocsFolder = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\"
```

which returns system path to My Documents, irrespectively from local system settings like language or nonstandard location of My Documents folders. Then it adds a backslash at the end.

It is more elegant (and the code becomes more portable) if you ask system about special folders than hardcode such data in your script.

More on Windows special folders in VBA you can find https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win027.htm

Comment: Telling someone to change their code without explaining why their code is wrong and your code is right, isn't a very useful answer for future readers.

Comment: You're right. It seemed to me to be obvious and self-documented. So I added an explanation which should shed some light.